# Angular sidebar overlaps content of pages

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

After creating the sidebar with angular cli:

```
ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name=navigation
```

the sidebar works fine but it overlaps the content of each page, how to change that? or do i have to write margin-left on each of the pages i am using?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you can see a demo here https://stackblitz.com/angular/ryxvnvrmemk?file=app%2Fsidenav-mode-example.ts

Comment: It's a bit late, but here goes.  You want to call the sideNav.toggle(true) function in hook(an ideal function on your component, eg ngOnInit).  You can make the sidenav control available to your component with @ViewChild('sidenav') sideNav:  MatSidenav;

Answer (score 2):

The 'autosize' property fixed it for me, but it comes with caveat, as per the documentation: 
[image: Angular Documentation]

https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api

Answer (score 1):

You can change `mat-sidenav` `mode` to `push` or `side`:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav 
      #drawer 
      class="sidenav" 
      fixedInViewport="true" 
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      mode="push"    <!-- THIS LINE -->
      >
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button type="button" aria-label="Toggle sidenav" mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()" *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>Application Title</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: i have used the 'side' mode but it doesn't appear side-by-side but it overlaps the content

Comment: For me this get's fixed after the first call to `drawer.toggle()`

Answer (score 0):

The router-outlet has to be inside the container (generated by schematics say "content here") and remove it from app.component.html

```
 <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
      <mat-sidenav 
          #drawer 
          class="sidenav" 
          fixedInViewport="true" 
          [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
          mode="push"   
          >
        <mat-toolbar color="primary">Menu</mat-toolbar>
        <mat-nav-list>
          <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
        </mat-nav-list>
      </mat-sidenav>
      <mat-sidenav-content>
        <mat-toolbar color="primary">
          <button type="button" aria-label="Toggle sidenav" mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()" *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
            <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <span>Application Title</span>
        </mat-toolbar>
       <router-outlet></router-outlet>  <!-- THIS LINE -->
      </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
```